# How do I get only values in one table that are found in the second table (table1.a found in table2.a and so forth)?

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is my regular table:

```
    A | B | C   (table1)
----------------
    1 | 2 | 3
    2 | 3 | 4
    3 | 4 | 5
    4 | 5 | 6
    7 | 8 | 9
```

I want to use this table to filter it out, possibly using joins, etc.

```
    A | B | C  (table2)
----------------
    1 |   |  
    3 |   |  
      | 4 | 
      | 5 | 
      |   | 5
      |   | 9
```

so that my result is the following:

```
    A | B | C
----------------
    3 | 4 | 5
```

My idea would be to join on each column in table2 like the following, so that if the table2 column is not null, then join, otherwise don't join:

```
SELECT
t1.* 
FROM table1 
JOIN table2 
ON ( t1.A = t2.A OR t2.A IS NULL)
AND ( t1.B = t2.B OR t2.B IS NULL)
AND ( t1.C = t2.C OR t2.C IS NULL)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you mean that you just need each of the values in a Table1 row to exist in one of the rows in table2? I'd use `where exists` for the three columns if that's the case.

Comment: By the way, this question is misleading as it has nothing to do with table value parameters, even though one of those tables might actually be stored that way.

Comment: Yes you are correct, in both comments.  I will update it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
select t1.*
from table1 t1
where exists (select 1 from table2 t2 where t2.a = t1.a) and
      exists (select 1 from table2 t2 where t2.b = t1.b) and
      exists (select 1 from table2 t2 where t2.c = t1.c);
```

This checks for the presence of each column in `table2`, only returning rows where all three columns are present.

Comment: This did what i needed to.  I just added at the end of each "exists" clause: "oR NOT EXISTS (Select 1 from Table2 t2 where t2.col is not null)", since I'm using the second table as a filter, so no values = no filter. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This one is slower but I find it reads better...

```
SELECT t.* 
FROM #table1 t
JOIN #table2 a
    ON a.A = t.A
JOIN #table2 b
    ON b.B = t.B
JOIN #table2 c
    ON c.C = t.C
```

Comment: Problem is with null values for this method.  If all of column C was null, I wouldn't want to join b/c I'm trying to use table2 as a filter (if no values in filter => don't filter). Thanks!

Comment: I don't think adding `OR NOT EXISTS...` will necessarily make it go faster. If you're concerned about speed, adding NC indexes on those columns may be better? Is maintainability a concern here at all?

Comment: Oh i meant OR NOT EXISTS not to make it go faster, but to not "filter out" the rows in table1 if the column x has no values in it